# Shifting bits for clearing the canvas, need the explanation for a short code

Tags: java, android, bitwise-operators

I would just need an explanation for this little chunk of code, since I'm having problems by looking in Java documentation.

The code:

```
public void clear(int color) {
    canvas.drawRGB((color & 0xff0000) >> 16, (color & 0xff00) >> 8,
    (color & 0xff));
}
```

This is from the book Beginning Android Games and the explanation below the code says:

> The clear() method extracts the red, green, and blue components of the specified 32-bit ARGB
>   color parameter and calls the Canvas.drawRGB() method, which clears our artificial framebuffer
>   with that color. This method ignores any alpha value of the specified color, so we don’t have to
>   extract it.

I understand the point but not really the implementation, can someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bytes, your `int` color is presenting as **AA RR GG BB**. First you "and" (`&`) it with 00 **FF** 00 00, extracting "red" value as 00 **RR** 00 00, then shifting result 16 bits, or 2 bytes right (`>> 16`) you receive 00 00 00 **RR**  which is equal to "red" value in initial color. The same with green and blue.

Answer (score 3):

[`drawRGB (int r, int g, int b)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29) takes three parameters, the red green and blue component of the color to draw.

Each colours has a value between 0 and 255 which can be represented using 8 bits for each colour (so 24 bits) and the last 8 bits for storing the alpha value.

Since an `int` has 32 bits you have:

```
Bits 
0-7 -> blue component
8-15 -> green component
16-23 -> red component
24-31 -> alpha value
```

So you see that a color can fit in an `int`. By applying the corresponding mask and shifting correctly the values, you can get the value of each color.

Let's say you have the integer `2084491`. Now you want to extract the three components of the RGB color represented by this value.

In binary on 32 bits, `2084491` is `00000000 01111111 00111010 00101101`.

Now let's apply the following operation:

```
red = (color & 0xff0000) >> 16 = 00000000 01111111 00111010 00101101 & 0xff0000) >> 16
                               = 00000000 01111111 00000000 00000000 >> 16
                               = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01111111
                               = 127
```

Now you get the value of the red component. Using the same technique with the right mask and shift you'll get the other values (for the green and blue component).

Also to be complete you could use the [`Color`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class if you wanted to:

```
public void clear(int color) {
    canvas.drawRGB(Color.getRed(color), 
                   Color.getGreen(color), 
                   Color.getBlue(color));
}
```

Those methods does exaclty the same thing under the hood:

```
/**
 * Return the red component of a color int. This is the same as saying
 * (color >> 16) & 0xFF
 */
public static int red(int color) {
    return (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
}

/**
 * Return the green component of a color int. This is the same as saying
 * (color >> 8) & 0xFF
 */
public static int green(int color) {
    return (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
}

/**
 * Return the blue component of a color int. This is the same as saying
 * color & 0xFF
 */
public static int blue(int color) {
   return color & 0xFF;
}
```